# Searchbar with NSManaged objects

Tags: iphone, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

    searchResultContacts = [contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

How to get result if contactArray contains MSManaged objects